# Wordpress intercept and edit out stylesheets/css

Tags: wordpress

Is there a programmatically way to intercept and edit out specific stylesheets/css in Wordpress before the out code goes to the client's side?

Fow example, I need to change everywhere these css:

`@media (max-width: 767px)` mobile portrait

`@media (max-width: 880px)` mobile landscape

`@media (max-width: 1024px)` tablet portrait

`@media (max-width: 1200px)` tablet landscape

to these:

`@media (max-width: 767px) and (orientation: portrait)` mobile portrait

`@media (max-width: 880px) and (orientation: landscape)` mobile landscape

`@media (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait)` tablet portrait

`@media (max-width: 1200px) and (orientation: landscape)` tablet landscape

Comment: Where is the stylesheet coming from? A plugin? The theme?

Comment: @disinfor Its coming from template of Elementor plugin.

Comment: If there is a way to dequeue the css file, you can then enqueue your own version of it in a php file with the content-type header set to serve css. In this file you get the contents of the original file, do the replacements and then echo it.